# Performing calcs on each column in Array, then passing to new colum

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

My task is to read every 48 elements of an array's column (usually 48, but left as variable if it changes) and perform some operations on those 48 numbers like sum, min, max, mean etc

I am actually do this succesfully with the following code.

```
total_demand = np.array([ca_demand, ny_demand, az_demand, fl_demand, ut_demand], dtype = float)

s = 0
e = 48

a = list()
b = list()
c = list()

for i in date_calc :
        n = ca_demand[s:e] #Data from a single column
        x = sum(n)
        mi = min(n)
        ma = max(n)
        diff = ma - mi
        mean = x//12
        reldif = mean//diff
        s += 48
        e += 48
        a.append(x)
        b.append(diff)
        c.append(reldif)
        gig_d = np.array(a)
        subtract_d = np.array(b)
        real_d = np.array(c)

return gig_d, subtract_d, real_d #returns single column array for each calc
```

This for loops works on a single column of data, and builds the values to those 3 respective datasets. However, I want to read in 4 columns to create a 4 column array, for each of those 3 datasets.

The bottom snippet is some pseudocode on how I'm thinking of the approach

```
for each column in the whole array I'm reading
        for i in date_calc: #original for loop
        
        return gig_d, subtract_d, real_d #As before, but added/appended to a full array

return full array for gig_d, subtract_d, real_d
```

I think theres an easy solution to this, but my brains not working right now. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a return statement at the end in your code? tell us something about the   shape of date_calc and ca_demand arrays. The number of elements ca_demand array is a multiple of 12?

Comment: The original array `total_demand` has half hourly datapoints in 5 columns each (incl ca_demand). What I'm doing with ca_demand is reading it's respective column in the array, slicing in 48 increments (mistake there, its 48, NOT 12!) to make a DAILY total of demand. I'm then performing those calculations you see in the for loop. My question is, how do do what you see in the for loop, not for one column of the array, but all columns (5 in total)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a daily total by slicing the dataframe rows using the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) function and divide the index by the number of elements you want on each group (`df.index//48`) to represent a day. You can use the [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#pandas-dataframe-agg) function to aggregate your operations (`sum`, `diff_minmax`, `realdiff`, or any other you decide to implement) over the row axis. Afterwards you can rename the columns of the multindex dataframe with `set_levels`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random((250,5)).round(2),
    columns=['ca_demand', 'ny_demand', 'az_demand', 'fl_demand', 'ut_demand']
)

INCREMENT = 48

def diff_minmax(x):
    return max(x)-min(x)

def realdiff(x):
    return x.mean()//(max(x)-min(x))

res = df.groupby(df.index//INCREMENT).agg([sum, diff_minmax, realdiff])
res.columns = res.columns.set_levels(['gig_d', 'subtract_d', 'real_d'], level=1)
print(res)
```

```py
  ca_demand                   ny_demand             ...  fl_demand        ut_demand
      gig_d subtract_d real_d     gig_d subtract_d  ... subtract_d real_d     gig_d subtract_d real_d
0     23.37       0.96    0.0     22.71       0.95  ...       0.94    0.0     22.18       0.94    0.0
1     24.76       0.98    0.0     27.88       0.98  ...       0.91    0.0     20.35       0.94    0.0
2     24.55       0.97    0.0     23.22       0.95  ...       0.98    0.0     24.17       0.95    0.0
3     22.57       0.97    0.0     23.28       0.94  ...       0.95    0.0     20.80       0.93    0.0
4     26.77       0.92    0.0     27.68       0.90  ...       0.98    0.0     23.36       0.98    0.0
5      6.53       0.73    0.0      3.78       0.84  ...       0.95    0.0      5.50       0.81    0.0
[6 rows x 15 columns]
```

To access a specific demand:

```py
In [144]: res.ut_demand
Out[144]:
   gig_d  subtract_d  real_d
0  22.18        0.94     0.0
1  20.35        0.94     0.0
2  24.17        0.95     0.0
3  20.80        0.93     0.0
4  23.36        0.98     0.0
5   5.50        0.81     0.0
```